# What do we call someone who is used by someone else to accomplish something for him?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, adjectives, vocabulary

Please can you find me a term for someone who had been used like a string puppet by some greater force or divinity to accomplish an act of vengence for them?

mediator and the likes sounds too... tame. I'd like something to make the character feel like some kind of string puppet in the hands of someone.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: The most common term is "puppet".

Comment: Is a religious martyr relevant in your context?

Comment: _Dupe_ or _stooge_ may work.

Comment: no, not really religious martyr but I'm trying to portray something alike. like the character feels like the messenger of a divinity but not to do something good like a prophet but something bad. (hence the act of vengence, as in the divinity is actually a vengress divinity.)

Comment: If you wish to inject, or don't mind injecting, a bit of legalese you could also consider, "unwitting accomplice."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you very much for your quick help!  this place is blissful! I think I'm gonna get addicted! (*_*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [**'Cat's paw'**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat's_paw)

> a person used unwittingly or unwillingly by another to accomplish the
>   other's own purpose.

This has its origin in the fable of the [Monkey and the Cat.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkey_and_the_Cat)

> In La Fontaine's telling, Bertrand the monkey persuades Raton the cat
>   to pull chestnuts from the embers amongst which they are roasting,
>   promising him a share. As the cat scoops them from the fire one by
>   one, burning his paw in the process, the monkey gobbles them up. They
>   are disturbed by a maid entering and the cat gets nothing for its
>   pains

Comment: OOOh!! This define exactly what I'm trying to convey! used to accomplish someone else's purpose!  'feeling like the cat's paw of a vengeredd divinity' Sounds good?

Answer (score 1):

"Tool" is common. I believe it was Lenin who coined the term "useful idiots" to refer to those whose adherence to some ideology  exceeded their common sense and could be manipulated in pursuit of it. "Puppet" (you used it) is certainly common, as is its variant "marionette". "Sock Puppet" is even more specific.

Comment: How could I not have thought of Tool x) I shall use use marionette and Stooge both. the phrase goes like: 'Watching it all unravel before his eyes and feeling like some stooge or the marionette of a vengeress divinity.' sounds good you guys think?

Comment: @Lola - Do you mean *vengeful*?

Comment: @Jim yes, i mean vengeful

Answer (score 0):

There are huge differences between 'used someone else' and 'used like a string puppet by some greater force or divinity…'and still, if it is to be by 'some greater force or divinity' then the usual term is 'instrument' as in 'instrument of God.'